# One Java application but 2 processes java and javaw?

Tags: java

i'm a bit lost with my application.

I run only one swing application (one window) but in the task manager i have two processes : java.exe and javaw.exe bopth consuming resources.

I found that javaw.exe is used when there's no java console, that's the case of my app.

So i'm wondering why is a "java.exe" process running and used by my application?

My app is launched by an exe (by launch4j) maybe it comes from that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely launch4j runs a java.exe console, which in turns starts a javaw.exe for running your GUI application. java.exe is for console applications only.

Comment: that is very probable, this is what happens with my JDeveloper and Netbeans installation

Comment: In that case the java.exe process shouldn't affect my application after it was launched no? But when i kill it, my app turns crazy by not displaying some panels and other components ... Or I misunderstood what you said?

Comment: What happens when you run your app without launch4j?

Comment: If I run it with "javaw -jar xxx.jar", the 2 processes are launched.
I also have some threads running in parallel of my GUI, but with no console maybe it comes from there?